# TFS shows unchanged files in "Pending changes" even when Local Workspace is used

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I'm using VS 2013 and s new TFS feature called [Local Workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx) mainly because of its ability to automatically detect changes and remove files from `Pending Changes` window if their content was not changed.

That works fine for regular files. But I have an issue for generated or dependent files - some of them still remain in `Pending Changes` even if there were no changes made to them. For example, I have a `.edmx` file with `.Context.tt` file, which has `<DependentUpon>HandymanContext.edmx</DependentUpon>` setting in project file. Now, when I update `.edmx`, the `.Context.tt` is also shown in `Pending Changes`, while it was not changed. Same thing happens for some `.cs` files, generated by T4 template.

And interesting thing, when I edit those files manually (add a space), undo changes (remove the added space) and save them, they are removed from `Pending Changes` as they should.

Is that a bug or there is some setting to prevent this behavior? Using `Refresh` option in `Pending Changes` window doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have generated files under source control. Use .tfignore to exclude those file types.

Visual Studio is likely detecting that while the contents of the file has not changed the file attributes have (the date time) and this is still a change.

It is best practice to always exclude generated files from source control. The build server will generate be files on demand.